# Code Igniter - Calling Multiple functions(methods) from a model or models to a Controller causes Fatal error

Tags: codeigniter-3

```
**My Controller File Name is Members.php and the code is...**
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Members extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct() 
       {
            parent::__construct();            
            //$this->load->model(array('Nationality_model','Religion_model'));  I tried this too

       }

    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('members/home');
    }

    public function customers()
    {

        if ($this -> session -> userdata('user_mallname') != "" )
        {

                $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
                $this->load->helper('security');
                $this->load->library('form_validation');

                $this -> form_validation -> set_rules('fullname', 'Full Name', 'trim|required|min_length[4]|max_length[40]|xss_clean|alpha_numeric');

                if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
                {

                    //$this -> load -> model('Nationality_model');
                    //$data['nat_list'] = $this -> Nationality_model -> natlist();

                    //$this -> load -> model('Religion_model');
                    //$data['reg_list'] = $this -> Religion_model -> reglist();


                    $this -> load -> model('Member_model');
                    $data['nat_list'] = $this -> Member_model -> natlist();
                    $data['nat_list'] = $this -> Member_model -> reglist();

                    $this->load->view('members/user-new', $data);
                }
                else
                {                   
                    // code goes here
                }

        }else{
            redirect('members/login', 'refresh');
        }
    }
}
```

**And the code in my Model member_model.php is**

```
<?php
 class Member_model extends CI_Model
 {

     public function __construct() {
         parent::__construct();
         $this -> load -> helper('mysqli'); // we are using Mysql Database with Stored Procedures
     }

     //NAT LIST  START    --  this function copied from    Nationality_model.php
     public function natlist() {      

         $sql = "CALL usp_natList()";        
         $parameters = array();
         $query = $this -> db -> query($sql, $parameters);  
         return $query -> result();
     }

     //NAT LIST END

     //REG LIST  START this function copied from Religion_model.php
     public function reglist() {

         $sql = "CALL usp_reglist()";        
         $parameters = array();
         $query = $this -> db -> query($sql, $parameters);  
         return $query -> result();
     }
     //REG LIST END
}
```

I tried both 1. calling from One model 2. calling from two different models.
all are showing ***Fatal error: Call to a member function result() on a non-object***   The error occurs in local host WAMP.   I did R&D in stackoverflow , I am unable to find answer. If anything wrong in my code, please let me know.  Thanks in advance.
NOTE: If I load only one method from any model., It works fine. !!

Comment: Thank You @Reece Kenney for Editing it...

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have autoloaded 'database' library in  config.php

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database');
```

or load it in your controller constructor.

```
...
parent::__construct();            
$this->load->database();
$this->load->model(array('Nationality_model','Religion_model')); $this->load->database();
...
```

Comment: $autoload['libraries'] = array('database'); in config.php or autoload.php?

In my autoload.php $autoload['libraries'] = array('database','form_validation','session'); 
Actually the problem is occur when we try to load one model with multiple functions or multiple models with multiple functions. I tried all your code @JazzBass

Comment: Actually the first project with same type of calling working fine... This problem occurs when we are working on another project in another system Windows

Comment: I found 1 mistake in my controller

public function __construct() {
  parent::__Construct();            
 }
the second line __construct is          Capital C          __Construct is correct..